# Is there any way to change font size of the Drop Zone text input

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

We have here a DropZone landing area

[image]

I would like to change the font size, but I do not find any appropriate parameter for it here: https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/theming

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Now I have the following inputs:

```
Dropzone.options.clientImageDropzoneSocial = {
paramName: "file",
acceptedFiles: "image/*",
parallelUploads: 1,
method: 'put',
resizeMimeType: 'image/jpeg',
resizeQuality: 1.0,
maxFiles: 1,
dictDefaultMessage: 'Drop image here',
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you inspected those elements in your browser to see if they have class names you can target?

[Based on the docs](https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/basics/layout) the elements have `dz-...` class names which you likely can style however you like with just regular CSS.